# What causes fonts to render badly in Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome

What can be the reason fonts render badly on Chrome?

OS: Windows 7 x64. I have tried reinstalling Chrome and even with the default install the fonts render like this.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wb2BrLs.png]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/Q4UAa7b.png]

Comment: Hi, Are you in 100% Zoom mode ?
Check your zoom setting, maybe from some reason your're at 80%/90%..?

Comment: It's the default zoom, I pressed ctrl+1 to reset zoom.

Comment: Try updaing your software, thats what google recommends..

Comment: I have already reinstalled Chrome and LastPass, both last versions.